# Differentiating between the same type of Exceptions, e.g. with Enumerable.Single()

Tags: c#, exception, linq-to-entities

Consider the following code:

```
int myId = 10;

try
{
    var me = this.Db.People.Single(p => p.Id = myId);
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    // Either I don't exist ("Sequence contains no elements"),
    // or more than one of me exists ("Sequence contains more than one element")
}
```

There are two conditions: Either 0 results are returned (which might not be too alarming, the person just doesn't exist), or more than 1 result are returned (which means something is seriously wrong assuming ID is supposed to be unique).

Ideally, I would like to catch and handle the exception if it was thrown because 0 results were returned, but not catch the exception if it was thrown because more than one results were returned (I can't handle this situation, but I don't want to simply ignore something that went very wrong).

Is there a way to differentiate between the two exceptions so I can only handle the case in which 0 results are returned, or is my only option to use SingleOrDefault and check for the null?

Comment: "or is my only option to use SingleOrDefault and check for the null?" -- You say that as if it's a bad thing, but that's exactly what I would do regardless of whether an alternative exists, just because it makes sense to avoid exceptions for situations that aren't all that exceptional.

Comment: `SignleOrDefault` literally does exactly what you want.  It only throws if there are more than one.  You just have to check for `null` in the case of zero.  Don't try to introduce exception handling where you don't need it.

Comment: @juharr hvd- I guess my aversion to SingleOrDefault arose from pre-C# 6.0 when if I, say, just wanted the person's name, I could easily try People.Single(...).Name and catch the exception, but SingleOrDefault would require first checking for the null, then accessing the property (of course I guess I could have just checked for a NullReferenceException in that case).  But the new null conditional operator with SingleOrDefault will give me the best of both worlds.  So I agree, SingleOrDefault is the way to go.

Comment: @Andrew You should always prefer a null check over catching `NullReferenceException`.  Basically avoid exception handling as much as possible as a general rule.

Comment: @Andrew Even before C# 6.0, custom extension methods were trivial to create that allowed you to write e.g. `db.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == myId).IfNotNull(p => p.Name)` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here:

> Either 0 results are returned (which might not be too alarming, the
>   person just doesn't exist),

This isn't "exceptional" because as you said, a person might not exist. So we shouldn't throw an exception when this happens. It's like going to a website and searching for a product. If no results are returned that's probably not an error. It just means that they don't sell that product.

> or more than 1 result are returned (which means something is seriously wrong assuming ID is supposed to be unique).

If it should be impossible to get more than one result, then more than one result should throw an exception.

That makes `SingleOrDefault` the best choice. Check for the null, because the query might not return anything. But if something completely out of bounds happens then there should be an exception.